# A prominent Mamzer Rabbi example?

Tags: history, rabbis, mamzer

Mishnah in Horayos 3,8 says:

> מַמְזֵר תַּלְמִיד חָכָם קוֹדֵם לְכֹהֵן גָּדוֹל עַם הָאָרֶץ:
>   (the scholar mamzer takes precedence over the ignorant high priest.)

Do we have a practical example of this statement? Did we ever (in our sources) precede a Mamzer Rabbi to a Cohen Gadol or similar?

Do we know of a prominent Rabbi that was a Mamzer?

Answer (score -1):

The matter is unlikely to be known.  There is a story in the Talmud [[Kiddushin 71a]](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.71a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) about a rabbi who said he could spot bastards on sight, but would never say anything because some great rabbis are among them.  This was later codified by the [Rema (on Shulchan Aruch Even Ha-Ezer 2.5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.2.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): If an unfit person is mixed in a particular family, then once it has become mixed it has become mixed and whoever knows about it may not disclose it".

Comment: I suspect you're referring to a gemara in the 4th perek of kiddushin (IMSMC) about a rabbi who *knew* of certain families that were of problematic lineage, but he wouldn't publicise it b/c some of them were very *important/powerful*.

Comment: @Loewian is referring to [Kiddushin 71a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.71a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

Comment: It seems that this is only applicable *to a family that is known to **blend** with one of these psulim*, but if one is known to be a Mamzer there's no "blending", so a Beis Din knows exactly who he is.